# No S3 media files in Heroku-deployed django project

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-s3, media

I am trying to serve the static and media files in my Django project (hosted on Heroku) from Amazon S3. Static files are now serving properly both locally and deployed, but media files are only working locally. I can verify that files are being added and served properly from my bucket when served by localhost, but neither saving nor loading works in production. When I try to serve a media image (which I manually added to the bucket), I get a 403 access denied error:

```
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Access Denied</Message>
    <RequestId>7430A21BE321C26B</RequestId>
    <HostId>
        h/c1VQF57wrLJ7JdHXuJ8LCrQdZL9PfQZN4G38Ihg8UYCxSt0znbxWfiTSDxz0dCooQoqgW9tpw=
    </HostId>
</Error>
```

When I attempt to save a file (through the Wagtail image upload), I get the rather generic `Internal Server Error - 500`. I'm at a loss as to what the problem is. The fact that I can get static but not media files is part of what's so confusing (and makes me think it's not just a permissions error). Here are the things that I think might be relevant to the problem.

**EDIT:** I realized I had `DEBUG = True` in my production settings from debugging a different production error. When I set that to False, I now get 403 errors for static files *and* media files.

My bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadForGetBucketObjects",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::owen-tribune/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::494147019987:user/jtebert"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::owen-tribune",
                "arn:aws:s3:::owen-tribune/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "somethingElse",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::owen-tribune",
                "arn:aws:s3:::owen-tribune/*"
            ],
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::494147019987:user/jtebert"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Relevant portion of `settings.py`:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '###########'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '################'
AWS_S3_HOST = 's3-us-east-2.amazonaws.com'

#AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = env['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
#AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = env['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'owen-tribune'

AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME

STATICFILES_LOCATION = 'static'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'owen.custom_storages.StaticStorage'
STATIC_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, STATICFILES_LOCATION)

MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'media'
MEDIA_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, MEDIAFILES_LOCATION)
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'custom_storages.MediaStorage'
```

Custom storages in `custom_storages.py`:

```
# custom_storages.py
from django.conf import settings
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage

class StaticStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    location = settings.STATICFILES_LOCATION

class MediaStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    location = settings.MEDIAFILES_LOCATION
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the static files issue was due to the compressor. I had the following code in my production settings:

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'

COMPRESS_OFFLINE = True
COMPRESS_CSS_FILTERS = [
    'compressor.filters.css_default.CssAbsoluteFilter',
    'compressor.filters.cssmin.CSSMinFilter',
]
COMPRESS_CSS_HASHING_METHOD = 'content'
```

This was only engaged when debug was False, which is why I was getting static files served correctly with debug=True. With debug off, the compressed static files were being stored within the app instead of in the S3 bucket, but the app was still looking for the compressed static files in S3. I solved this issue by simply commenting out these lines in the settings.

Media files are also now uploading correctly, but the auto-generated resizing still isn't working. I'll post a separate question about that and update here if I get a resolution.